# 2D Array Equivalence?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, equivalence

I'm trying to determine whether or not two 2d arrays are equivalent in terms of integer values. When I input the following values for the arrays:

```
First Array:
1 1 1 
1 2 2 
1 1 1 

Second Array:
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1 

//I get:
Equivalent
//which is not true, since the arrays are not identical.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code for this problem is attached below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. This is my first time posting on S.O., so please forgive me and correct me if I've done anything wrong in terms of formatting anything. Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class TwoDimensionalArrayEquivalence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initialize the first two arrays
        int[][] firstArray = new int[3][3];
        int[][] secondArray = new int[3][3];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask user to input first array
        System.out.println("Please input an array of 9 numbers: ");
        int userInput = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < firstArray.length; column++) {
                userInput = scan.nextInt();
                firstArray[row][column] = userInput;
            }
        }

        //ask the user to input the second array
        System.out.println("\nPlease input another array of 9 numbers: ");
        int userInput2 = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < secondArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < secondArray.length; column++) {
                userInput2 = scan.nextInt();
                secondArray[row][column] = userInput2;
            }
        }

        //print the first array user has input
        System.out.println("\nFirst Array:");
        for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < firstArray[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(firstArray[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //print the second array user has input
        System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");
        for (int row = 0; row < secondArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < secondArray[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(secondArray[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //call method CheckArrayEquality to check for array equivalence
        CheckArrayEquality(firstArray, secondArray);

    }



    public static void CheckArrayEquality(int[][] firstArray, int[][] secondArray){

        boolean decider = false;

        //here, I'm trying to traverse the arrays by incrementing by each row and column
        for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < firstArray[row].length; column++) {
                //Below: if the value in a specific row and column in firstArray is equal to 
                //the value in the same specific row and column in secondArray, then decider is 
                //"true". Else, decider is "false"
                if(firstArray[row][column] == secondArray[row][column]){
                    decider = true;
                }

                else {
                    decider = false;
                }
            }   
        } 

        //if-else statement for printing out whether the arrays are equivalent or not
        //based on what the decider has become
        if (decider == false) {
            System.out.println("\nNot equivalent");
        }
        else if (decider == true) {
            System.out.println("\nEquivalent");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are printing *last* value of `decider`, so it is value of lastly checked indexes. If array is at one point not equal exit the loop. Also evaluating a value and printing it shouldn't usually isn't done in same method. Consider changing your `CheckArrayEquality` method to `return` boolean value and after that in main method call it and print its result.

Comment: `decider = false;` is overwritten by `decider = true;` on the next matching element. If you find a single non-matching element, break and stop checking, report false immediately. This is also prone to crash if the array lengths aren't equal, so it's a good idea to not assume anything. Don't print anything in a method that should check equality.

Comment: You are looping through whole 2d array. The moment it fails, you need to break the loop

Comment: BTW `if (condition) {set to true} else {set to false}` can be replaced with `set to (condition)`.

Comment: @Pshemo So, that means I would have to include a break statement I'm guessing? I'll also change the method type to boolean as well. Thank you by the way!

Comment: @Viswa So, I would include a break statement in the if-else statements then? Thank you!

Comment: Or just using your bool-flag in your condition!

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! I've also realized that as well. I'm assuming I would need to include a break statement in the if-else statements as well as change the method type to boolean (and decide whether or not the array lengths are equal before doing so).

Comment: `break` is considered by some as code-smell. How about instead make method *return* false when it sees that arrays are not equal like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023610?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the value of `decider` in every iteration, which means the only value you'll get in the end is if the last entries are equal.

A better implementation would be:

```
public static boolean array2dEquals(int[][] firstArray, int[][] secondArray){
    if(firstArray.length != secondArray.length) return false;
    for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
        if(firstArray[row].length != secondArray[row].length) return false;
        for (int column = 0; column < firstArray[row].length; column++) {
            if(firstArray[row][column] != secondArray[row][column]) return false;
        }   
    } 
    return true;
}
```

usage:

```
if(array2dEquals(firstArray, secondArray)) {
    System.out.println("\nEquivalent");
} else {
    System.out.println("\nNot equivalent");
}
```

This implementation also checks the array length first, so you won't get any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the arrays do not match in size.

---

But unless you care about every last bit of performance, it would be best to just use what java already provides:

```
if(Arrays.deepEquals(firstArray, secondArray)) {
    System.out.println("\nEquivalent");
} else {
    System.out.println("\nNot equivalent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what your app does is returning Equivalent if the last integer of the matrix is equal to the second one.

### Example

```
First Array:
1 1 1 
1 2 2 
1 1 1 

Second Array:
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1 

Equivalent



First Array:
1 1 1 
1 2 2 
1 1 1 

Second Array:
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 2 

Not Equivalent
```

### Fix:

```
public static void CheckArrayEquality(int[][] firstArray, int[][] secondArray){

        boolean decider = false;

        //here, I'm trying to traverse the arrays by incrementing by each row and column
        linesLoop:
        for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < firstArray[row].length; column++) {
                //Below: if the value in a specific row and column in firstArray is equal to
                //the value in the same specific row and column in secondArray, then decider is
                //"true". Else, decider is "false"
                if(firstArray[row][column] == secondArray[row][column]){
                    decider = true;
                }

                else {
                    decider = false;
                    break linesLoop; // Don't check others, we already have a non equal values.
                }
            }
        }

        //if-else statement for printing out whether the arrays are equivalent or not
        //based on what the decider has become
        if (decider == false) {
            System.out.println("\nNot equivalent");
        }
        else if (decider == true) {
            System.out.println("\nEquivalent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only breaks out of the inner loop and continues checking on the outer loop. Just `return false;` and skip all the boolean/break/printing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing by reference `==`. Arrays are objects, so you got to use `equals`. Or even better, [`Arrays.deepEquals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) from Arrays library:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
        int[][] arr2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
        System.out.println(checkequals(arr, arr2));
    }

    private static boolean checkequals(int[][] arr, int[][] arr2) {
        return Arrays.deepEquals(arr, arr2);
    }
}
```